# In fluid Pressure why we only take only force due to upper layer of fuids that is (density)$hg$?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, density

**Question**
In fluid Pressure why we only take only force due to upper layer of fluids that is (density)$hg$ But lower level also apply Force (up thrust from lower molecule of fluid) to maintain the layer in Equilibrium.

Comment: Pascal recognized that pressure is isotropic, meaning, at a given depth, it acts equally in all directions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the Euler's equation with $\vec{f}$ being the external force exerted on fluid elements
$$\partial_t \vec{v}+ (\vec{v}.\vec{\nabla})\vec{v}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\vec{\nabla} P+ \vec{f}$$
You are talking about a fluid at rest in a gravitational field. So we need to set $\vec{v}=0$ and $\vec{f}\equiv\vec{g}=- g \hat{z}$:
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\vec{\nabla} p= \vec{g}$$
If $\rho$ is assumed to be constant and $p_0$ is for $z=h$, you get
$$p(z)=p_0+ \rho g (h-z)$$
The point is that the presence of $\vec{g}$ introduces a preferred direction; e.g. downward in your case. For this reason gradient of pressure  is downward, equivalent to the point you mentioned.
**However, in the absence of gravitational field, i.e.; $\vec{g}=0$, this is not the case.**

One more point. To calculate the **force** exerted on a surface in the fluid, you need to calculate
$$F_i=-\int \Pi_{ij}dS_j$$
Here $dS_j$ is the $j^{th}$ component of the surface element and
$$\Pi_{ij}=p \delta_{ij}+ \rho v_i v_j$$
is the momentum flux density tensor. Let's consider two cases:

1. The force exerted on a horizontal surface at z, from above: $dS_z=  ds \hat{z}$
2. The force exerted on a horizontal surface at z, from below: $dS_z= - ds \hat{z}$

For a fluid at rest, $\Pi_{zz}=p(z)$ and so
$$ 1) F_z = -\int p ds = -\big(p_0+ \rho g (h-z)\big) S$$
$$ 2) F_z = -\int p (-ds) = +\big(p_0+ \rho g (h-z)\big) S$$
They have the same magnitude but opposite directions.